# gcc command line argument fsplit-paths

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, optimization, command-line-arguments

One of the optimization flags in gcc is `-fsplit-paths`. I have noticed that enabling it improves the speed of one of my program in a statistically significant manner.
However, I am unclear as to how this option works exactly.

According to the doc:

> Split paths leading to loop backedges. This can improve dead code elimination and common subexpression elimination.

Is anyone able to shed some lights as to how this works exactly?

Comment: Not sure either, but maybe the test cases in the GCC test suite could help: [split-path-1.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/tree-ssa/split-path-1.c)…[split-path-7.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/tree-ssa/split-path-7.c)

Comment: Thanks for this. Still not completely clear to me.

Comment: If you want to find out what it's doing, you can use GCC's `-S` option to have it produce assembly instead of machine code, and compare the code generated with `-fsplit-paths` to the code generated without it.

Comment: Seems some graph transformation on [back edges](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/PLT/PLT8.6.4.html). LLVM has [something similar](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2009-10/ScalarEvolutionAndLoopOptimization.pdf).